# symfony 4 showing 500 error "something is broken" when running in dev via server:run

Tags: php, symfony4

getting 500 error "something is broken" when running in dev mode via server:run. I don't know what happened, why doesn't show the actual error? also I have to keep clearing cache.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: yea I see the error. but I don't know why it doesn't show the actual error in the browser since it should be running in dev. I also have to clear the cache to see changes. Its like its running in prod but I thought server:run always run in dev?

Answer (score 0):

changed APP_DEBUG = 1.
or
APP_ENV=dev APP_DEBUG=1 php bin/console server:run